# Modal with zoom in zoom functionality in jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

So I am using the [imgViewer2 plugin](https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2).
I need to design a modal with the options to zoom in and out on the image selected.I am facing an issue with the zoom in zoom out option which is appearing on the web page along with the image instead of appearing inside the modal window.

Here is my working link for the same [link](http://-https://codepen.io/shivanit2/pen/jKYBwY).

Comment: What is the issue you are talking about?

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 1):

on modal popup the zoom in/out are appearing but its not visible because of its low z- 
  index value, try to fix it like below.

```
 <style> 
.CustomStyleForImageViewer{
        z-index:1100 !important;
        background:transparent !important;
    }
</style>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.full-image').imgViewer2({});
        $('.viewport').addClass("CustomStyleForImageViewer");
        $('.map-image').click(function () {
            var $src = $(this).attr('src');
            $('.full-image').attr('src', $src);
            $('.map-image').removeClass('focused-on');
            $(this).addClass('focused-on');
        });
    });
```

But it leads to further problems which need to be sorted out as well. 
  This answer is just a hint on how to make zoom in/out divs visible on modal popup, you will need to fix the further problem which are gonna occur in this scenario , test it and you will know it

Answer (score 0):

you can embed your own zoom in zoom out buttons inside modal. I have modified your code a little bit. This is just a hint on how to work out your problem.

```
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="image-section-main">
                <div class="full-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                               <input type="button" title="ZoomIn" value="ZoomIn" onclick="funcZoomIn()" style="position:absolute; top:50%;" />
                        </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                               <img class="full-image" src="https://s15.postimg.cc/l1wcg52or/house1.png">
                        </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="button" title="ZoomOut" value="ZoomOut" onclick="funcZoomOut()" style="position:absolute; top:50%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <ul class="main-image-list">
                    <li class="image-and-text">
                        <img id="img1" class="map-image focused-on" src="https://s15.postimg.cc/l1wcg52or/house1.png">
                        <div class="map-text">Ground Floor</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="image-and-text">
                        <img class="map-image" src="https://s15.postimg.cc/pnsgohvxn/house2.jpg">
                        <div class="map-text">First Floor</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="details-main">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <script>

    var Zoom = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.map-image').click(function () {



            var $src = $(this).attr('src');

            $('.full-image').attr('src', $src);

            $('.map-image').removeClass('focused-on');

            $(this).addClass('focused-on');

            $('.full-image').imgViewer2({

                zoomable: true,

                dragable: true

            });

        });

    });


    function funcZoomIn() {

        Zoom = Zoom + 0.1;

        $(".image-section-main").css('-transform', 'scale(' + Zoom + ')');

    }

    function funcZoomOut() {

        Zoom = Zoom - 0.1;

        $(".image-section-main").css('-transform', 'scale(' + Zoom + ')');

    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have to achieve this using the plugin so I guess embedding buttons might not work.The plugin is not sticking to the content inside the modal and I am not able to figure out why.

Comment: i can only tell you that on modal popup the zoom in/out are appearing but its not visible because of its low z-index value, try to fix it.

Comment: But I guess that will break the container.Also do you know any other plugins to achieve the same which work well in modal?

Comment: did you try to implement the the solution i gave in the second answer? try that and find out the next problems